# React - View doesn't update after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React component since a long time but for some reason my view doesn't update after doing an `ajax` call and setting a state.

So, basically, I have a state of `clients` which is at the beginning an empty array. In the lifecycle method `componentDidMount` I do an `ajax` call and in the `.then` promise I set the state to the response. But for some reason, the view doesn't get updated since the `p` tag saying "there are no clients" still is there, and a `map` function I wrote doesn't output any results.

I am sure the `clients` state is updated since I console.log the result after setting the state and Also in my React dev tools I can see that the clients state has 1 item.

For context, I am using this component in a Laravel project but that doesn't make any difference I guess.

My code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Clients extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clients: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getClients();
    }


    getClients() {
        axios.get('/oauth/clients')
            .then(({data}) => {
                this.setState({
                    clients: data,
                }, () => {
                    console.log(this.state.clients);
                });
            });
    }


    render() {

        const clients = this.state.clients;

        return (

            <div>
                {/* Begin card */}
                <div className="card card-default">

                    <div className="card-header">
                        <div style={flex}>
                            <span>
                                OAuth Clients
                            </span>

                            {/* <a class="action-link" tabindex="-1" @click="showCreateClientForm"> */}
                            <a className="action-link" tabIndex="-1">
                                Create New Client
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="card-body">

                        { clients.length === 0 &&
                            <p className="mb-0">
                                You have not created any OAuth clients.
                            </p>
                        }

                            <table className="table table-borderless mb-0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Client ID</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Secret</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                    { clients.map(client => {

                                        return (

                                            <tr key={client.id}>

                                                <td style={alignMiddle}>
                                                    {client.id}
                                                </td>

                                                <td style={alignMiddle}>
                                                    {client.name}
                                                </td>

                                                <td style={alignMiddle}>
                                                    {client.secret}
                                                </td>

                                                <td style={alignMiddle}>
                                                    <a className="action-link" tabIndex="-1">
                                                        Edit
                                            </a>
                                                </td>

                                                <td style={alignMiddle}>
                                                    <a className="action-link text-danger">
                                                        Delete
                                            </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                        );

                                    }) }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                    </div>

                </div>
                {/* End card  */}
            </div>

        );
    }
}


// Styles
const flex = {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
};

const alignMiddle = {
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
};

export default Clients;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the request successful? Have you tried to log `data` in the axios callback? Maybe the request fails and you need a `catch` to see it. `.catch(error => console.error(error)`. It might also be that `data` is an empty array in the response.

Comment: how about `({data})` vs `(data)`  ? I mean what if response may be not be: `{data: [clients here]}`

Comment: @Tholle As I mentioned above I am sure that the clients state is updated, since I do a `console.log` on the `this.state.clients` after setting the state. I've added a catch but like I said, I am pretty sure the state is updated, so I didn't got any errors back.

Comment: @num8er No, normally you get a `response` back from an `ajax` call. In that `response` object you've got a `data` object with all the data. Using `{data}` will destructure the object so I don't have to use `response.data`. Learn more about that here https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/.

Comment: Very interesting. [Your code works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/yjv4rr1jlz).

Comment: @Tholle Really, really weird.. I almost think it's something about the env. I work in

Comment: @Gijsberts can you post the array you're getting from `this.state.clients` after the ajax call comes back?

Comment: @Gijsberts Your code is working fine separately, Don't know what is the problem in you app but your working code is here. check link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yp2mjz